# Regex to extract ADL FQDN from String

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to extract the Datalake Store FQDN from a given string using a Regex in Scala. Can someone please help?

```
Input = adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net/123/wds/xyz=456/

Output = adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net
```

The ADL FQDN can have `[a-zA-Z_-]` in its definition. I've tried the following:

```
scala> val ADLStorePattern = "(.*) ([a-zA-Z_-]+) (.net) (.*)".r
ADLStorePattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = (.*) ([a-zA-Z_-]+) (.net) (.*)

scala> val ADLStorePattern(adl, _, _) = "adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net"
scala.MatchError: adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net (of class java.lang.String)
  ... 32 elided

scala> val ADLStorePattern(adl, _) = "adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net"
scala.MatchError: adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net (of class java.lang.String)
  ... 32 elided

scala> val ADLStorePattern(_, adl, _) = "adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net"
scala.MatchError: adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net (of class java.lang.String)
  ... 32 elided

scala> val ADLStorePattern(_, adl, _, _) = "adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net"
scala.MatchError: adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net (of class java.lang.String)
  ... 32 elided

scala> val ADLStorePattern = "([a-zA-Z_-]+) (.net) (.*)".r
ADLStorePattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = ([a-zA-Z_-]+) (.net) (.*)

scala> val ADLStorePattern(adl, _) = "adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net"
scala.MatchError: adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net (of class java.lang.String)
  ... 32 elided

scala> val ADLStorePattern(adl, _, _) = "adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net"
scala.MatchError: adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net (of class java.lang.String)
  ... 32 elided
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the FQDN from the 1st group of the Regex pattern as follows:

```
val url = "adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net/123/wds/xyz=456/"

val pattern = """(adl://[^/]*)(/.*)?""".r

val fqdn: String = url match {
  case pattern(x, _) => x
  case _ => "No match!"
}
// fqdn: String = adl://asbwje-fhs.azuredatalakestore.net
```

The 2nd optional group is to cover cases where the URL consists of only the FQDN part.